# c socket: recv and send data simultaneously

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, fork

I'm having issues with my client side implementation of client server chat program where multiple clients connect. The issue is that i'm coming across is that how exactly should i be sending (chat message to another client) and receiving (chat message from another client) at the same time? What's happening is that i'm always sending data and never reading. Do i need to fork and have one read and the other send?

here is the relevant code

**client side**

```
while(1) {

  fd_set rfds, wfds;
  FD_ZERO(&rfds);
  FD_ZERO(&wfds);

  FD_SET(serverSocket, &rfds);
  FD_SET(serverSocket, &wfds);

  if(select(serverSocket+1, &rfds, &wfds, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
      perror("select");
      exit(-1);
  }

  if (FD_ISSET(serverSocket, &rfds)) {
     // we got data, read it
  }
  if (FD_ISSET(serverSocket, &wfds)) {
     printf(">");

     // read keyboard
     sendLen = 0;
     while ((cmd[sendLen] = getchar()) != '\n')
        sendLen++;
     cmd[sendLen] = '\0';

     // send the data
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you try with 2 different threads for read and write separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the file descriptor  0 (standard input) in the select as well, then read chars and buffer them, and when the socket is available for writing, copy the entire buffer on it. In this way you just block reading on the standard input all the time.

add

```
FD_SET(0, &rfds);
```

so select will return when user types something as well.

you must also use fcntl to set stdin as non-blocking.
Then everytime select tells you there's data on stdin do something like that:

```
while(read(0,buffer+filled,1)>0) {}
```

Make sure to put another condition to exit the loop if the buffer is full.

then when you can write on the socket do a send, of the size of the amount of bytes you have in your buffer, check if all of it has been written, or move the leftovers bytes at the beginning of the buffer.

That while(getchar()) is blocking you preventing you from receving any messages.

Comment: could you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: Alright, so it's almost working besides one small minor issue that needs to be resolved. Somehow i need to notify the client it's okay for them to type (note the printf(">")) but whats happening is that since there is no newline in the statement, it's not being outputted to the client until the client hits the return key.

Comment: You can say STDIN_FILENO to be a little more clear than "0" when you mean stdin.

Comment: For that one minor issue, try doing a fflush(stdout) after the printf()

Comment: You can check if the user pressed \n. Also to avoid incoming and outgoing data to intermix you might want to use ncurses, but it's not an easy library to use.